# If you cast Blindness/Deafness as a 3rd level spell, can you target one creature with both effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The Player's Handbook states that when cast as a 3rd level or higher spell, Blindness/Deafness can target additional targets equal to the difference between the spell slot the spell is cast at and its base spell slot level of 2.

My question is, would it be legal to cast Blindness/Deafness as a 3rd level spell, but instead of having either effect (blindness OR deafness) target two creatures, have it target one creature with both effects (blindness AND deafness.)

I'm having a hard time deciding whether this would provide an overpowered effect, as it increases the amount of disabilities one creature will suffer from, but lessens the number of creatures affected by the spell.

Perhaps it could be legal provided the targeted creature gets to make a separate CON save against each effect?

Comment: Keep in mind the only difference will be cosmetic. Since disadvantage doesn't stack it will have little or no mechanical difference.

Comment: Not entirely @Escoce, targeting the same creature twice would also mean that it needs to succeed 2 Constitution saving throws else suffer disadvantage further if both failed and the target were blind and deaf, I would believe they would need to pass a Con saving throw to remedy each.

Comment: @DavidJacobsen fair enough, I wasn't considering that, only considered that disadvantage doesn't stack

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Per rules as written, **no**. The spell clearly says either one or the other, not both.

However, if a DM was to allow it, it probably wouldn't break much. The biggest concern would be that stealth against the target would likely be an automatic success, but that doesn't mean much when the target clearly knows that its senses are being suppressed.

Answer (score 18):

## The spell clearly states that you cannot target the same creature multiple times

This is from the spell text:

> At Higher  Levels. When    you cast    this    spell   using   a   spell   slot    of  3rd level   or  higher, you can target  **one   additional  creature**  for each    slot    level   above   2nd.

The same creature again isn't an additional creature.  Each target needs to be a different creature.

Comment: +1. While I agree, I think you could make an argument against it. I'm not personally prepared to do that though.

Comment: @PremierBromanov If I said you could buy one apple for $0.50, or if you paid me $0.75 I would give you the original apple and an additional apple, would you be happy if you paid me $0.75 and I gave you the same apple twice?

Comment: No but I would be happy to cast the same spell on someone twice. I don't think your analogy holds up.

Comment: @Percival In your analogy, apples are consumable: once given, they're no longer available to give.  That would only be true of the question if casting the spell consumed the target in a way that excludes them from future castings.  You analogy is equivalent to “if I cast blindness on a creature, can I cast it again to make them more blind?”

Comment: @Percival: Instead of apples, think of Cheech's special penny pussy sale speech in _"From Dusk Till Dawn"_. Getting the same service a second time for only a penny works perfectly well, nobody would complain.