# Do Fire Shield of fire and Fire Shield of ice stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, stacking

If I cast Fire Shield for fire and ice, will they stack?

Comment: I have closed your question as a felt it was a duplicate of [the marked one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135631); if you feel this is not the case feel free to [edit] or drop a comment explaining why